# Serialize Enum as String for validation using Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, enums, jackson

I'm trying to validate an Enum using the custom validator, in my custom validator I'm trying to return a custom message when a parameter does not exist in the enum values.

Bellow my enum

```java
public enum Type {
    MISSING_SITE,
    INACTIVE_SITE;
}
```

Bellow my `PostMapping` method

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/line-kpi", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Operation(summary = "Find Kpis by one or more customer property")
public ResponseEntity<List<KpiDTO>> findKPILineByCustomer(@RequestBody @ValidCustomerParameter CustomerParameter customerParameter, @RequestParam @ValidExtractionDate String extractionDate) {
    var linesKpi = Optional.ofNullable(
            kpiService.findKPILineByCustomer(
                    Optional.ofNullable(customerParameter.getEntityPerimeter()).orElse(List.of()),
                    Optional.ofNullable(customerParameter.getName()).orElse(List.of()),
                    Optional.ofNullable(customerParameter.getIc01()).orElse(List.of()),
                    Optional.ofNullable(customerParameter.getSiren()).orElse(List.of()),
                    Optional.ofNullable(customerParameter.getEnterpriseId()).orElse(List.of()),
                    LocalDate.parse(extractionDate)
            )
    );
    return linesKpi.map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(KPIS));
}
```

I can't switch the type of enum to string in the method itself because I'm using swagger which displays a nice selection list for enums.

Unfortunately, when I try to give a different value for Type, it returns a bad request and my validators are not triggered.

So I'm trying to serialize my enum to be interpreted as String when it arrives at the controller and to do that I need to use Jackson, I tried to look for a solution but I can't find a good one for my case.

Bellow are my validators

```java
public class ReportTypeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidReportType, Type> {
    private String globalMessage;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidReportType constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
        globalMessage = constraintAnnotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Type type, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (Arrays.stream(Type.values()).filter(type1 -> type1.equals(type)).toList().isEmpty()) {
            constraintValidatorContext
                    .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(globalMessage + ", report type does not exist")
                    .addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = ReportTypeValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Valid
public @interface ValidReportType {
    String message() default "Invalid value for report type";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Could anyone tell me how can I turn my enum as a string so my validator could handle it?

Comment: I think i don't get the full complexity of the problem, but do you "just want" (something like): `globalMessage + ": " + type.name() +", report type does not exist"` ??

Comment: ..but i doubt, this code would ever execute... (what if you/someone send `Type.UNDEFINED` ??)?

Comment: and for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70069155/serialize-enum-as-string-for-validation-using-jackson#comment123864158_70069155), there is better solution: [Interpolating constraint error messages](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/7.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-message-interpolation) (you can use placeholders and many more...)

Comment: the problem is not about enum value, it's about spring default handling for parameters, because he checks value of enum before calling validators, and since I have an emum parameter he checks if the value of parameter is a valid enum for such type, if not he returns bad requests..I don't want him to do the default handling for enums, I want him to call directly for the validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, I was able to do it by implementing a new converter, which will convert string to a valid enum value or an INVALID value:

```
public class TypeConverter implements Converter<String, Type> {
    @Override
    public Type convert(String source) {
        if (Arrays.stream(Type.values()).filter(type -> Objects.equals(type.toString(), source)).toList().isEmpty()) {
            return Type.INVALID;
        }
        return Type.valueOf(source.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

After that I added a new Configuration for my converter:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new TypeConverter());
    }
}
```

Also I had to hide the INVALID value of my enum from swagger by adding the @Schema annotation:

```
@Schema(allowableValues = {"MISSING_SITE","INACTIVE_SITE"}, type = "String")
public enum Type {
    MISSING_SITE,
    INACTIVE_SITE,
    INVALID
}
```

Finally in the validators, I should reject the INVALID value and display a custom message:

```
public class ReportTypeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidReportType, Type> {
    private String globalMessage;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidReportType constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
        globalMessage = constraintAnnotation.message();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Type type, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (type == Type.INVALID) {
            constraintValidatorContext
                    .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(globalMessage)
                    .addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The annotation for the previous validator:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ReportTypeValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Valid
public @interface ValidReportType {
    String message() default "Invalid value for report type";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a special enum constant indicating the request JSON contained an invalid enum constant name. The request JSON should never actually contain the name of this enum constant. Also add a method that Jackson will invoke while deserializing to convert a JSON string to an enum constant. This method returns the special enum constant if the JSON string is not a known enum constant name.

```java
public enum Type {
    MISSING_SITE,
    INACTIVE_SITE,

    @JsonProperty("SHOULD NEVER ACTUALLY APPEAR IN REQUEST JSON")
    INVALID;

    /**
     * Converts enum constant name to enum constant.
     *
     * @param name
     *         enum constant name
     * @return enum constant, or {@link #INVALID} if there is no enum constant with that name
     */
    @JsonCreator
    public static Type valueOfOrInvalid(String name) {
        try {
            return Type.valueOf(name);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return INVALID;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `ReportTypeValidator.isValid(` method, check the enum constant is `INVALID`.

```java
if (type == Type.INVALID) {
    // Add constraint violation.
```

Comment: inspirational! I did as you said but it didn't work, maybe because I'm accepting the enum as @RequestParam and not as a json value in the method of controller, all what I'm getting now is a bad request, could it be the reason?